# how to write auth based Firestore Rules for specific collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a collection called `Orders` and I have two other collections for `Users` & `Drivers`. I want the `Orders` collection to be accessible only by the UID's that inside the `Drivers` collection.

All the people signed into the app are users, but `Drivers` are the only users that can access the `Orders` documents.

The logic is to check if the user is signed and the `Drivers` collection contains a field that has the UID of that user. If the collection field contains the UID of that user, then he can access that collection of document.

```
allow write, read: if isSignIn() & `Driver colletion contains that user UID`
```

How can I do that and if I can I need some help write that code?

[image: here is how the Database look like]

[image: here are the Orders collections]

Here are my rules and I did not change that much in it. All that I know is this code is for every document in my database, so I need to write some specifics

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow write, read: if isSignIn();
    }
    
    function isSignIn(){
    return request.auth != null;
    }
    
  }
}
```

here is how I'm getting the data from Firestore

```
func newOrders(){
        
        let fireStore = Firestore.firestore()
        let doc = fireStore.collection("Orders")
        
        self.driverListener = doc.addSnapshotListener { (query, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            }
            guard let querysnap = query else {return}
            
            querysnap.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                
                if change.type == .added {
                    
                self.DriverOffers = []
                for document in querysnap.documents{
                        
                    let snap = document.data()

                guard let orderLoc = snap["orderLocation"] as? GeoPoint else {return}
                    
                guard let docId = snap["docId"] as? String else {return}
                guard let name = snap["name"] as? String else {return}
                guard let phone = snap["phone"] as? String else {return}
                guard let time = snap["time"] as? String else {return}
                guard let marketName = snap["marketName"] as? String else {return}
                guard let price = snap["amount"] as? String else {return}
                guard let userImg = snap["userImg"] as? String else {return}
                guard let storeImg = snap["storeImg"] as? String else {return}
                guard let order = snap["order"] as? String else {return}
                guard let userid = snap["userUid"] as? String else {return}
                guard let timestamp = snap["date"] as? Timestamp else {return}
                let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp.seconds))

                guard let userlocation = snap["userLocation"] as? GeoPoint else {return}

                    let offer = driverOrdersData(docId: docId, userUid: userid, name: name, phone: phone, amount: price, time: time, marketName: marketName, storeimgUrl: storeImg, userImgUrl: userImg, date: date, orderDetails: order, orderLocation: orderLoc, userLocation: userlocation, distance1: distance1, distance2: distance2 )
                    
                    self.DriverOffers.append(offer)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.DriverOrdersTV.reloadData()

                    }
                    }
                
            }
            }
        })
        
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you share what other collections look like in a screenshot ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have updated the quistion

Comment: @Swift: I see you unaccepted my answer. Can you clarify what is still missing from it?

Comment: after trying for a couple of days this answer actually didn't work, I only got permission failed for the document in the XCode debugger but I'm still getting the documents from that collection @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If the document is already in the local cache (for example: if you change the rules after it's been cached, or if it was read for a different user who does have access) it is possible that the cache returns the document - even if the server doesn't. Specifics depends on how you implement the read operation, which you didn't share, but since this should not be a normal use-case, I recommend uninstalling and reinstalling the app to get rid of the cached data if this happens while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check in security rules whether a document exists with a specific value in it, as that would require your rules to query the collection and would be costly and not scale.

The trick to implement this use-case (and many others) is to use the UID of a user for the document ID in the `Drivers` (and probably also `Users`) collection. You can do this by adding those documents with something like

```
let uid = ....; // wherever you get the UID from
firebase.firestore().collection("Drivers").doc(uid).set({ uid: uid });
```

Now with that structure in place, you can check whether a document with the specific UID *exists* in your security rules, which is possible:

```
function isDriver() {
  return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Drivers/$(request.auth.uid))
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [accessing other documents in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).